# Fastify swagger doc is generating a OPTIONS API in swagger doc under default tag

Tags: swagger, fastify

I am facing an weird issue. In my swagger doc, I am always seeing  default OPTIONS API is getting listed without any specification from my routes.

I am registering fastify-cors which seems the issue.

```
fastify.register(require('fastify-cors'), {});
fastify.register(require('./routes/routes'));
```

This is the screen shot:

[image]

My versions are:

```
    "fastify": "^3.19.0",
    "fastify-auth0-verify": "^0.5.2",
    "fastify-cors": "^6.0.1",
    "fastify-swagger": "^4.8.2",
    "fastify-mongodb": "^2.0.1",
    "mongo-sanitize": "^1.1.0"
```

What's the way out? It looks really odd as my swagger is going to be out for our customers/integrators.

Thanks,
Pradip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That route is the `preflight` route handler.

To skip it you must disable it:

```
fastify.register(require('fastify-cors'), {
  preflight: false
});
```

Or simply hide it:

```
fastify.register(require('fastify-cors'), {
  hideOptionsRoute: true
})
```